# constants class in php

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, constants

I once heard it's good to have one class with all your application constants so that you have only one location with all your constants.

I Tried to do it this way:

```
class constants{
    define("EH_MAILER",1);
}
```

and

```
 class constants{
         const EH_MAILER =1;
 }
```

But both ways it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you hear that?  I think it's best to couple the constant with where it will be used.  Also, what is EH in your example?  I think that constant deserves a better name.

Comment: If you're doing a more procedural style application, I could see an argument for an include full of define()s, but, if you're working with OO, putting all the constants in a single class makes no sense.  They belong with the class that they're (most) relevant to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the current version of PHP this is the way to do it:

```
class constants
{
   const EH_MAILER = 1;
}

$mailer = constants::EH_MAILER
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

---

Starting with PHP 5.3 there's better way to do it. [Namespaces.](http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)

consts.php

```
<?php
namespace constants
const EH_MAILER = 1

...
```

other.php

```
<?php
include_once(consts.php)

$mailer = \constants\EH_MAILER
```

Comment: This is the way I would suggest doing it.

Comment: This is the solution i was looking for.
Without the namespaces of course!
Tnx

Comment: Wouldn't that be \constants\EH_MAILER, or at the very least constants\EH_MAILER?

Comment: @Adam: You're right.There's been a lot of discussion about which will be namespace separator, in early versions it was :: (like in C++)

Answer (score 0):

What php version are you using?

See php's [page](http://php.mirrors.ilisys.com.au/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) for class constants